# Prove an inequality concerning $\sqrt[3]{4a^3+4b^3}+\sqrt[3]{4b^3+4c^3}+\sqrt[3]{4c^3+4a^3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, radicals

Let $a,b,c$ be positive. I need to prove

$\sqrt[3]{4a^3+4b^3}+\sqrt[3]{4b^3+4c^3}+\sqrt[3]{4c^3+4a^3}\leq \dfrac{4a^2}{a+b}+\dfrac{4b^2}{b+c}+\dfrac{4c^2}{c+a}$

Thanks!

Comment: Without loss assume $a\ge b\ge c$, writing $b=a\beta$, $c=a\gamma$ for $1\ge beta\ge \gamma$.  Then we may rewrite $\sqrt[3]{4+4\beta^3}+\sqrt[3]{4\beta^3+4\gamma^3}+\sqrt[3]{4\gamma^3+1}\le 4a \left( \frac{1}{1+\beta}+\frac{\beta^2}{\beta+\gamma}+\frac{\gamma^2}{\gamma+1}\right)$.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that

$$\sum \frac{4a^2 - 4b^2} { a+b} = \sum (4a-4b) = 0. $$

Hence, we have

$$\sum \frac{4a^2} { a+b}  = \sum \frac{4b^2} {a+b}$$

Hence, we may rewrite the RHS and make it more symmetric, namely

$$\sum \sqrt[3]{4a^3+4b^3} \leq \sum \frac{4a^2} {a+b} = \sum \frac{ 2a^2+2b^2} { a+b}.$$

Now, we can break it up into the individual terms, and just show that

$$ \frac{ a^3+b^3} {2} \left( \frac{a+b}{2} \right)^3 \leq \left( \frac{a^2+b^2} {2} \right)^3$$

This is true because

> [Newton] $$S_1 S_3 \leq S_2^2$$
>  [Maclaurin] $$S_1^2 \leq S_2$$

Comment: Good +1 for you.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\sqrt[3]{\frac{a^3+b^3}{2}}\leq\frac{a^2+b^2}{a+b}\Leftrightarrow(a-b)^4(a^2+ab+b^2)$, we obtain
$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt[3]{4(a^3+b^3)}\leq\sum_{cyc}\frac{2(a^2+b^2)}{a+b}=\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{2(a^2+b^2)}{a+b}+2(a-b)\right)=\sum_{cyc}\frac{4a^2}{a+b}.$$
Done!

Answer (score 0):

I know that Calvin already answered your question, but I was bored and resoluted to prove it only with elementary tools. So here goes my proof for what is worth:

Manipulate the RHS to find symmetry
$$\frac{4a^2}{a+b}+\frac{4b^2}{b+c}+\frac{4c^2}{c+a}$$
$$4\left(\frac{a^2}{a+b}+\frac{b^2}{b+c}+\frac{c^2}{c+a}\right)$$
$$4\left(a+b+c-\frac{ab}{a+b}-\frac{bc}{b+c}-\frac{ac}{c+a}\right)$$
$$2\left(a+b-\frac{2ab}{a+b}+b+c-\frac{2bc}{b+c}+a+c-\frac{2ac}{c+a}\right)$$
$$2\left(\frac{a^2+b^2}{a+b}+\frac{b^2+c^2}{b+c}+\frac{a^2+c^2}{c+a}\right)$$
Observe that 
$$0\le(2x-y)^2$$
$$0\le4x^2-4xy+y^2$$
$$3x(y-x)\le x^2-xy+y^2$$
$$3x(y^2-x^2)\le x^3+y^3$$
Substituting

$x=ab,\,y=a^2+b^2$
$$3ab(a^2b^2+a^4+b^4)\le(a^2+b^2)^3+a^3b^3$$
$$(a^2+b^2)^3+8a^3b^3+3ab(a^4+b^4-2a^2b^2))\le2(a^2+b^2)^3$$
$$(a^2+b^2+2ab)((a^2+b^2)^2-2ab(a^2+b^2)+4a^2b^2)+3ab(a^2-b^2)^2\le2(a^2+b^2)^3$$
$$(a+b)^2((a^2+b^2)^2-2ab(a^2+b^2)+4a^2b^2)+3ab(a+b)^2(a-b)^2\le2(a^2+b^2)^3$$
$$(a+b)^2((a^2+b^2)^2-2ab(a^2+b^2)+4a^2b^2+3ab(a-b)^2)\le2(a^2+b^2)^3$$
$$(a+b)^2((a^2+b^2)^2+ab(a^2+b^2)-2a^2b^2)\le2(a^2+b^2)^3$$
$$(a+b)^2((a^4+b^4+ab(a^2+b^2))\le2(a^2+b^2)^3$$
$$(a+b)^2(a+b)(a^3+b^3)\le2(a^2+b^2)^3$$
$$4(a^3+b^3)(a+b)^3\le8(a^2+b^2)^3$$
$$\sqrt[3]{4(a^3+b^3)}\le\frac{2(a^2+b^2)}{a+b}$$
$$\sqrt[3]{4(b^3+c^3)}\le\frac{2(b^2+c^2)}{b+c}$$
$$\sqrt[3]{4(a^3+c^3)}\le\frac{2(a^2+c^2)}{a+c}$$
$$\sqrt[3]{4(a^3+b^3)}+\sqrt[3]{4(b^3+c^3)}+\sqrt[3]{4(a^3+c^3)}\le2\left(\frac{a^2+b^2}{a+b}+\frac{b^2+c^2}{b+c}+\frac{a^2+c^2}{c+a}\right)$$
$$\sqrt[3]{4(a^3+b^3)}+\sqrt[3]{4(b^3+c^3)}+\sqrt[3]{4(a^3+c^3)}\le\frac{4a^2}{a+b}+\frac{4b^2}{b+c}+\frac{4c^2}{c+a}$$
I like how it looks like a cup.